# Sql server query to find out when employees were absent 5 days or more

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called timedetail where working time is entered (doecode w) or vacation time (doecode vac). This is what I have so far but it is returning worked time as well.

```
TimeDetail

empnum  tsdate     doecode
123     1/1/2013   VAC
123     1/2/2013   VAC
123     1/3/2013   VAC
123     1/4/2013   VAC
123     1/5/2013   VAC
123     1/6/2013   W
123     1/7/2013   W
123     1/8/2013   W
123     1/9/2013   VAC
111     1/1/2013   W
111     1/2/2013   VAC
111     1/3/2013   W
111     1/4/2013   VAC
111     1/5/2013   VAC
```

empnum 123 should get returned but not 111

```
WITH R AS (
SELECT
   empnum, tsdate,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empnum ORDER BY tsdate)
   - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empnum ORDER BY tsdate, doecode) as grp
FROM
   timedetail t
WHERE
   doecode in ('VAC') 
--   and not exists (
--      select * from timedetail b where doecode < ' '
--      and b.tsdate = t.tsdate and b.empnum = t.empnum
--   )
)
SELECT empnum, MIN(tsdate) AS fdt, MAX(tsdate) AS tdt, COUNT(*) AS no_of_days
FROM R  
GROUP BY empnum, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
ORDER BY empnum, MIN(tsdate), MAX(tsdate)
```

Comment: Please add table structure, example data, expected output and what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you maybe format your query for readability's sake?

Comment: I do believe you've been reading my answers on stackoverflow. Grin. :)

Comment: Good edit @Mike. Not sure why the first attempt got rejected. It was definitely not a frivolous edit. Perhaps the reviewers did not notice the sql was completely sans code formatting ;-)

Comment: I tried adding the table structure and sample data but it didn't keep the format I had

Comment: When I try running this data on SQLFiddle, it **does** return 123 but not 111: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faf97/2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the new requirements of ignoring gaps within a group (of `VAC` or `W`), and tolerating duplicate values, the query you provided has two problems.

1. It was partitioning by only `empnum` twice. This isn't going to return a useful result. Instead, you needed the second one to partition by `empnum, doecode`.
2. Due to the need to partition by `doecode`, you can't exclude any `doecode` values from the derived table and you must move `WHERE doecode = 'VAC'` out into the main query.

I have cured these problems in the following query:

```
WITH R AS (
   SELECT
      T.*,
      Grp = 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.empnum ORDER BY T.tsdate)
         - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.empnum, T.doecode ORDER BY T.tsdate)
         -- the subtracted value has to partition by doecode
   FROM
      dbo.TimeDetail T
)
SELECT
   empnum,
   FromDate = MIN(tsdate),
   ToDate = MAX(tsdate),
   DayCount = COUNT(DISTINCT tsdate)
FROM R
WHERE doecode = 'VAC' -- must be out here
GROUP BY empnum, grp
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tsdate) >= 5 -- distinct dates
ORDER BY
   empnum,
   FromDate
;
```

[See this working in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0248f/1).

I used `>= 5` rather than `> 4` because I think it expresses the intent more clearly.

Using the following "tricky" test data:

```
empnum tsdate     doecode
------ ---------- -------
123    2013-01-01 VAC
123    2013-01-02 VAC
123    2013-01-03 VAC
123    2013-01-03 VAC -- duplicate row
123    2013-01-04 VAC
123    2013-01-04 VAC -- duplicate row
123    2013-01-07 VAC -- skipped a weekend
111    2013-01-01 W
111    2013-01-02 VAC
111    2013-01-03 W
111    2013-01-04 VAC
111    2013-01-06 W
111    2013-01-07 W
111    2013-01-08 W
111    2013-01-09 W
111    2013-01-10 W
```

This will return:

```
empnum FromDate   ToDate     DayCount
------ ---------- ---------- --------
123    2013-01-01 2013-01-07 5
```

For the record, if your data was sequential and couldn't duplicate, you would need only one `Row_number` function. Grouping sequential items is as simple as Itzik Ben-Gan's grouped islands solution:

```
WITH R AS (
   SELECT
      T.*,
      Grp = DateAdd(day, 
         -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.empnum, T.doecode ORDER BY T.tsdate),
         T.tsdate
      )
   FROM
      dbo.TimeDetail T
   WHERE
      doecode in ('VAC') 
)
SELECT
   empnum,
   FromDate = MIN(tsdate),
   ToDate = MAX(tsdate),
   DayCount = COUNT(*)
FROM R  
GROUP BY empnum, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
ORDER BY
   empnum,
   FromDate
;
```

Comment: Would there be anyway to include weekends. Another words if someone took off Tuesday through Monday but since no rows exists for Sat and Sunday the query won't return anything

Comment: Also if they have multiple rows of vacation on the same day it counts that day twice

Comment: These new requirements change things a bit. They actually take things right back to the original query you had! For what it's worth, in the future please provide the most tricky example data you can think of, and try to state these additional requirements up front so people don't waste time! That will get you better answers faster. Plus, changing requirements after people have spent time answering is a bit unfair.